# Tomcat invalid lib directory

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ubuntu

I am trying to deploy a basic HelloWorld web app with tomcat via eclipse, but I can't seem to deploy it with eclipse.  This is the error message I get whilst deploying manually.

```
May 20, 2012 10:44:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/home/chris/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory:         [false], canRead: [false]
May 20, 2012 10:44:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/home/chris/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory:     [false], canRead: [false]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:406)
```

I am running ubuntu 11.10 and i installed eclipse manually and installed tomcat through eclipse.
I am working on getting my code into github, and will post the link when i confirm its working.

How can i test my code via tomcat on ubuntu?

Comment: Looks like you have folder and file problems, look at the warning in the stacktrace. Verify your tomcat installation and startup with http://localhost:8080 and by setup a demo application on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download from Apache tomcat site. http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

I assume you are using tar.gz file.
Extract it on uBuntu using tar command.

You will have this kind of folder structures:

- bin
- lib
- webapps
- logs
- etc.

If you want to start your tomcat. go to bin. find file and run **startup.sh** (linux)
Then go to your webapps.
Put your .WAR files here. Let's say your **HelloWorld.war**

If you are using Eclipse. You can add your tomcat directory to Server. 
Go to Server, Add Server, and register your tomcat there. Point it to the directory where you extract the tar.gz file. Hope it helps

Comment: Ended up installing it manually and getting the WTP plugin.

Thanks for the help!